# Managing a computation onlt with iterators Python

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to do this very simple thing in a more pythonistic way which would involve only one iterator:

```
>>>for i in xrange(10):
...    for j in xrange(i+1,10):
...        print i,j
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
0 8
0 9
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
2 7
2 8
2 9
3 4
3 5
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 9
4 5
4 6
4 7
4 8
4 9
5 6
5 7
5 8
5 9
6 7
6 8
6 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

What I'd like to do is something like this, which would involve only one iterator:

```
>>>from itertools import tee
>>>iter1=iter(xrange(10))
>>>for i in iter1:
...    iter2=tee(iter1,1)[0]
...    for j in iter2:
...        print i,j
```

This obviously doesn't work, yielding:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
0 8 
0 9
```

Since when I've iterated all the way through iter2 I've also iterated all the way through iter1.

Is there any way I can manage to achieve this ? I'm using Python-2.7

**EDIT**:
What I'd like to do is the same thing with any iterable, not only numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(10), 2):
    print i, j
```

**EDIT** correnspond to EDIT of the question

itertools.combinations accept iterable. For example,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> def gen():
...     yield 'egg'
...     yield 'spam'
...     yield 'ham'
... 
>>> for i, j in itertools.combinations(gen(), 2):
...     print i, j
... 
egg spam
egg ham
spam ham
```

Comment: Ok but what I aim to do is more general, in fact I'd like to do this which any iterable. I'm going to edit the question

Comment: Hum it works already with any iterable. Thanks I hadn't think about this very simple solution